Prove no group order 96 is simple
Does this proof hold?
$96=2^53$
Let $H$ be a 2-sylow subgroup in $G$.
Then $|H|=32$
I know by a prior lemma that $[N[H]:H]$ is congruent to $[G:H]$ (mod p) so therefore $|N[H]|/32$ is congruent to 1 (mod 2).
This means $|N[H]|$ is either 32 or 96 as it can't be any smaller than 32 as H is a subgroup of it and it can't be any larger than 96 as it is a subgroup of G and the only numbers between 32 and 96 which are congruent to 1 (mod 2) when divided by 32 are 32 and 96.
If $|N[H]|$ is 32 then $H=N[H]$ therefore $H$ is normal in $G$ so $G$ is not simple.
If $|N[H]|$ is 96 then $N[H]=G$ therefore $H$ is normal in $G$ as $H$ is normal in $N[H]$.
Either way $G$ has a normal subgroup H so is not simple.
This seems to easy and I'm worried I missing something and the proof doesn't hold. Any suggestions?

I'm not sure if by $N[H]$ you mean the normalizer of $H$ or the normal closure of $H$. Either way, exactly one of "$H=N[H]$ therefore $H$ is normal in $G$" and "$N[H]=G$ therefore $H$ is normal in $G$" is false, They cannot both be correct.

From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: "A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."

By contradiction, let $G$ be simple. Then, by Sylow III, there are three $2$-Sylow subgroups, so (again by simplicity) $G$ acts faithfully on three elements, namely $G$ embeds into $S_3$, which is impossible by cardinality reason.

@ArturoMagidin i meant the normaliser of H :) why can they not both be correct?

Because if the normalizer of $H$ is $H$, that means $H$ is not normal in $G$. It is not normal in any subgroup of $G$ that properly contains it.

@ArturoMagidin true thanks for pointing this out :) In that case i have no idea how to show a group order 96 is never simple lol

@hannah by Burnside it's solvable (it's order is $p^aq^b.$) then it can't be simple.

Assume $G$ to be simple. As you observed, the number of Sylow $2$-subgroups of $G$ is either $1$ or $3$. If it is $1$, then the Sylow $2$-subgroup is normal and you have a contradiction. So let us assume that there are $3$ Sylow $2$-subgroups. Pick two different ones say $P$ and $Q$. They both have order $32$. Now $\#PQ=\frac{|P| \cdot |Q|}{|P \cap Q|}$. Hence $96 \geq \#PQ=\frac{32 \cdot 32}{|P \cap Q|}$. And it follows that $|P \cap Q| \geq 10\frac{2}{3}$, so, since $P \cap Q$ is a $2$-group, $|P \cap Q|=32$ or $|P \cap Q|=16$. Since $P \neq Q$, we can only have $|P \cap Q|=16$. In addition, since $|G:P|=|G:Q|=3$, we must have $G=\langle P,Q \rangle$.

Now let us look at $N_G(P \cap Q)$. Observe that $P \cap Q \unlhd P$ and $P \cap Q \unlhd Q$ (namely, $|P:P \cap Q|=|Q:P \cap Q|=2$). So $P \subseteq N_G(P \cap Q)$, and similarly $Q \subseteq N_G(P \cap Q)$. Since $G=\langle P,Q \rangle$ this yields $G=N_G(P \cap Q)$, that is $P \cap Q \unlhd G$, the final contradiction.

Note You can prove the statement in a different way by looking at the conjugation action of $G$ on the Sylow $2$-subgroups. From this one can conclude that $G$ can be embedded in $S_3$, which is nonsense of course.
